# Using Sync Framework 2.1 to synchronise SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 Express with WCF

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

We have built an application which synchronises a central SQL Server 2008 database with multiple client SQL Server 2008 Express databases.

Although this application is successful we would like to ensure that the transfer of data is secure. In order to do so we are trying to re-write our application to synchronise using a web service implemented with WCF.

The example in the following article seems very good and I have managed to re-write most of our application.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208#content

However, in our application we need to assign the ApplyChangeFailed event handler to both the local provider and the remote provider. (please see example code below)

((SqlSyncProvider)_syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler(SynchronisationWizardClient_ApplyChangeFailed);

((SqlSyncProviderProxy)_syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler(SynchronisationWizardServer_ApplyChangeFailed);

As the Remote provider is now a SqlSyncProviderProxy object the ApplyChangeFailed event is not available.

The example in the article does not use the ApplyChangeFailed event so there is no reference to it in any of the sample code. I assume we need to amend some of the WCF contracts and classes in order to be able to set ApplyChangeFailed on our SqlSyncProviderProxy.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you want the WCF service to call back your client everytime ApplyChangeFailed event is raised?

The WCF service has the reference to the SqlSyncProvider, you can handle the ApplyChangeFailed event on the service side without having to send it back to the client. If you need to resolve conflicts, you can resolve it on the service side.

Comment: server side after configuring the SqlSyncProvider just added:
serverProvider.ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(ServerProvider_ApplyChangeFailed);